# Deleted Recovery partition on Dell XPS 13. Now unable to boot into windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bootloader

Mine is Dell xps 13 ultrabook shipped with windows 7. I thought of installing ubuntu, so I unknowingly deleted recovery partition, formatted it and installed ubuntu. Now ubuntu is working fine. But in grub, I am not able to see windows. So I followed this tutorial How to Manually Repair Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems - How-To Geek to fix my windows. But it didnt work

In second screenshot, Windows 7 option didnt appear. I clicked next and did Startup repair which didnt help and then went to command prompt to execute the two commands

bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

The first command executed successfully but the second command gave me an error "the volume does not contain a recognized file system"

How can I recover my windows . Please help. I need windows badly

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure deleting the recovery partition is incidental to the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm your windows partition still exists from linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. In case if someone else also faces similar problem, here is the solution

1)Some times system repair may not work

2)Its because C partition may not be active - In my case atleast this happend - so fix is - First make it active - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71432-partition-mark-active.html

3)Now try system repair. It works :)

So be careful while deleting recovery partition. If you delete it, make the main partition active and then try system repair.

Thanks guys :)

I just shared all my dual booting experience here - in case - it can help some one - http://rajeshksv.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-fix-dual-booting-issues-windows.html